Stability of non-inverting op-amp amplifier using bode plot
With a non-inverting op-amp amplifier, just have Rin and Rf, when finding the stability of the amplifier with bode plot, do I need to consider Rin and Rf if I am given the open loop gain AOL(jw) (transfer function) of op-amp.  I know closed loop gain ACL(jw) can be found by feedback factor β and open loop gain.  When drawing bode plot to find stability, do I draw open loop gain or closed loop gain?

Strictly speaking, neither! What you want to see is if your loop gain can become equal to -1 at any given frequency. If that happens, your closed-loop gain will be infinite:
$$ A_{CL} (s) = \frac{A(s)}{1 + T(s)} $$
where \$ T(s) \$ is the loop gain. Now, if you already know what the feedback factor \$ \beta (s) \$ is, you can use the relation \$ T(s) = \beta (s) A(s) \$ and conclude that \$ T(s) = -1 \$ if \$A(s) = -1 / \beta (s) \$ at any frequency \$ s = j\omega\$. That means you must check if \$ A(s) \$ intersects the \$ -1 / \beta (s) \$ curve in magnitude and phase. For example, let us say in your case \$ R_f = R_{in} \$ and \$ \beta = 1/2 \$. Then, you must check if \$ A(j\omega) \$ intersects the magnitude line of 2 = 6 dB with a phase of equal or less than \$ -180^{\circ} \$. If that happens, then your loop gain becomes -1, the closed-loop gain becomes infinity in magnitude, and your system will most-likely become unstable in the presence of feedback.

P.S. Most circuits will be placed in some sort of phase-less passive feedback. That means \$ \angle \beta (s) = 0 \$ and \$ \vert \beta (s) \vert < 1 \$ for all \$ s = j\omega \$. Thus, you can check an absolute worst case of \$ \beta = 1 \$ (strongest possible feedback in this case) for stability. Of course, you would want to assume that your initial feed-forward system is BIBO-stable to begin with, which is usually the case. One interesting exception to this would be the double integrator circuit with \$ A(s) = \ 1 / s^2 \$. You can try and find out whether stronger negative feedback makes a double integrator more stable or less stable!

Understood. But why does T(s) have to equal to -1 instead of 0dB (phase margin)?

@yolopoi what is $ 20\log_{10}(|-1|) $?

I know -1 cannot be log.  But where does -1 come from?

@yolopoi the magnitude of -1 is indeed equal to 0 dB with a phase of 180 degrees. The significance of -1 for the loop gain is that it makes the closed loop gain infinite. The system can then sustain an output with a zero input! Equivalently, you can say the poles of the closed-loop system cross to the right-half plane there.

@a360pilot It is important to realize that there are two different definitions for loop gain: With or without consideration of the necessary phase inversion (180deg) within the loop (at the summng junction resp. inv. opamp input or anywhere within the loop). In the first case (including the 180deg) the critical point in the s-plane for stability analyses is at "+1" and in the second case it is at "-1". When we measure/simulate the gain of the complete (open) loop, the loop gain must be, therefore, negative. Consequently, the T(s) in the denominator is negative and the denominator is (1-T(s))

@LvW yes, absolutely correct. However, the mathematical convention aside, I believe the idea of stability is to avoid an infinite closed-loop gain, at least in theory. It may go beyond that in practice.
